# how to use setTimeout on a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This question might be simple to most web developers but I am pretty new and cannot figure out the way to put a settimeout function on what I would like to show on a page. below is the example of the code I would like to add a timeout for.

```
import React from "react";

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <h4>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </h4>
      <h4>About Me</h4>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

and here is my app.jsx which then will be exported to be used in index.js . What I want is to have lets say 5s delay before my Navbar function shows.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Contact from "./Contact";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Contact />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: From a UX perspective that sounds counter-intuitive. Out of interest why would you delay displaying a key piece of functionality from the user like that? But:  in order to do this you would need a state to store a `isVisible` variable, a timeout in a `useEffect` hook that updates the state when it completes, and your JSX to read the `isVisible` state and render the nav when the state changes.

Comment: @Andy true that I just wanted to see an example using my own piece of code since I could not understand existed code that was on other websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `setTimeout` in your App Component. It should look like this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Contact from "./Contact";

function App() {
  const [showNavBar, setShowNavBar] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setShowNavBar(true);
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {showNavBar ? <Navbar /> : null}
      <Contact />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: You probably want to assign the timeout to a variable, and then use a [cleanup function to clear it](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1).

Comment: @Harkunwar is it possible to declare the useEffect function in a seprate file and then import it to the App file?

Comment: @Namran, yes you can. You need to write a custom hook for it.

Comment: @Kamran lot of [reusable hooks here](https://github.com/streamich/react-use). `useTimeout` might be what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

your can add a state 'loading' and add useEffect hook and then use setTimeout there and change the loading state to false after 5seconds. in return section all you need to do is check if loading is false you show the  otherwise it will show nothing.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Contact from "./Contact";

function App() {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  
   useEffect(() => {
   setTimeout(() => {
     setLoading(false);
   }, 5000);
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
     {!loading && <Navbar /> } 
      <Contact />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```